# What is the reason of explosion of batteries?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

In social sites we see many pictures showing awareness of not using smartphone while charging because of the reason that battery explode while charging, is really batteries explode and if yes than what is the reason behind it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your question sounds interesting but is a bit tough to understand.  Can you give an example of an article or posting that refers to batteries exploding curing charging?  Are you asking about any types of phone in particular?

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/busting-the-myth-yes-cell-phones-can-explode-42582/ go through it

Comment: So is bursting the same as exploding? http://nypost.com/2016/09/11/samsungs-new-smartphone-may-catch-fire-us-officials/

Comment: Which type of batteries? That is an important question!

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for a battery to explode is the contents of it heating to a point where it exerts a force on the battery too large for it to handle. Basically, if the battery feels very hot, it could be under large pressure and the object that it is powering should be powered off if possible. The recent reports of smartphones catching fire are due to a manufacturing error by Samsung on the Galaxy Note 7. A portion of these phones were not insulated correctly and it caused a short circuit that ended up burning holes through the phones. This was not an explosion, but the phones did catch on fire. In conclusion, you can use your phone while charging if it's not a Galaxy Note 7 (which has been recalled).

Comment: It would be useful to know how to put out such a fire.

Comment: Like iPhone more?